# An inequality for norms involving convolutions

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, convolution

I need to prove/disprove the following existence theorem:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \quad \exists f\in L^1(\mathbb R), g\in L^p(\mathbb R) : \quad (1-\epsilon)\|f\|_1\|g\|_p < \|f\ast g\|_p,
$$
where
$$
1\leq p \leq \infty, \quad f\ast g (x) \equiv \int_{\mathbb R} f(y)g(x-y)\,dy.
$$

What comes to my mind is Young's inequality for convolutions, $\|f\ast g\|_p \leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_p$. But, alas, I'm unable to make any use of it here, not even sure whether it may be helpful here.

What could be a possible strategy to tackle this problem? Maybe, I should somehow approximate the functions $f$ and $g$ by sequences of (smooth, Schwartz, ... ) functions? Will appreciate any clarifying hint, or reference to the literature! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Set any $g \ne 0$ (continuous if $p = \infty$) and let $f_n$ be an approximate identity. Then $f_n * g$ converges to $g$ in $L^p$, and hence $\|f_n * g\|_p > (1 - \varepsilon) \|g\|_p = (1 - \varepsilon) \|f_n\|_1 \|g\|_p$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: This is the _answer_ I was writing...

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you for your comment. I would like then to ask a moderator to transfer this question to Math SE instead, if possible. At the moment I'm not sure I know how to do that, but I definitely will, as soon as possible. Thank you!